# How do I set current working directory to the project root in atom?

Tags: node.js, plugins, editor, atom-editor

In atom, `process.cwd()` always returns `'/'`. So if I do things like `fs.readFile('myfile')` it cannot find the file. 'myfile' is in the root of the project where atom opens from. Obviously I can't hardcode the absolute path. How do I achieve it?

Comment: An overview of your file structure would be helpful.

Comment: Hi, I just want the path of the opened project by atom not the atom package path. The file structure of the user could be anything. Thanks.

Comment: Aaaah you're actually asking about an Atom plugin or something? Because you've tagged this post [electron]. It sounds like your question isn't about Electron.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I just thought Electron was related.